# Is There A Free C# PDF Generator That Works In Medium Trust?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I have been looking through the usual suspects of PDF generators for C# (iTextSharp and PDFSharp etc).

The problem is none of them work in a medium trust environment. Does anyone know of a library that does 100% work in medium trust? Preferably free, but at most $100 or $200?

**Update:**

Before someone comments iTextSharp works in medium trust if you change the `assembly.cs` to allow partially trusted callers, it doesn't. I have tried all the 'hacks' and it simply does not work in a medium trust environment - you get the following error even with the partially trusted caller line added.

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.
SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Comment: Is leveraging a Silverlight to generate the PDF for you on the client-side viable?

Comment: have you tried MigraDoc?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well, but currently this question is little more than a poll. Exactly what are you generating? A file on the filesystem? That will always require trust; can you output it to a server or to isolated storage?

Comment: MigraDoc/PDFSharp don't work in medium trust as I have stated above. I'll email your Victor in a moment.

Comment: I see you added the last comment 22 hour ago, but i haven't gotten any emails from you yet. Just to make sure you got the address right. Btw, i also ported our full featured product - Siberix Report Writer to work in Medium Trust. The port of Report Writer won't be free (PDF Sparkle is free), but i can provide a good discount.

Comment: @Victor You are still trying to use Stack Overflow as free advertisement. This is wholly unacceptable. Flagging your comments.

Comment: Seems even the products people say work in medium trust, actually don't fully work and are stripped down versions - And most of the time the features you need, such as word to PDF are the features that have been stripped out for medium trust support.